# Java -Tela cheia em 16Bit

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen

Como posso colocar uma JFrame em tela cheia e mudar a resolução da tela usando:

```
device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(Width,Height,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN));
```

Devo usar uma nova library?

Agradeço

Comment: Não compreendi qual é o problema. Poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "Tela cheia em 16bit"?

Comment: Você está usando o Swing?

Comment: Ta ligado quando vc usa o GraphicsDevice para defnir qual JFrame será exibida em tela cheia e/ou mudar a resolução da tela? No caso, quero mudar a resolução da tela e defini-la coo 16 Bits

Sim, estou usando o Swing para o JFrame e o java.awt para o GraphicsDevice

Comment: O que é essa variável device? Adicione o restante do código pra ficar mais fácil de entender.

Comment: @gato provavelmente ele fala disto https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSRuW.jpg, antigamente os drivers de video chegavam até 16bit, depois vieram tecnologias melhores (como 24bit e 32bit), no entanto o modo 16bit foi mantido, ele se refere a capacidade de cores que um driver dispõe. 16 = 65.536 cores, 24 = 16.777.215 e 32 = 4.294.967.296... O intuito do autor ao usar 16bit talvez seja criar um jogo (ou outra coisa) que não exija tantas cores... PS: Josesk hoje algumas placas não suportam usar menos que 32bit, provavelmente por isso a nenhum script irá funcionar, ele continuará 32bits.

Comment: Sim exatamente disso que estou falando :3 vlw

Comment: Josesk chegou a ler a resposta depois que a editei?

Answer (score 1):

É bem provável que sua placa de vídeo ou seu driver de vídeo **não suportem** a mudança, principalmente se o seu driver for genérico, por exemplo esta usando um sistema operacional mais recente que a sua placa de vídeo, por exemplo no meu caso o vídeo só disponibiliza 32bit, isto pode ser devido a placa (onboard) ou porque instalei o Window 8.1 para uma placa mais antiga, do qual seu suporte só vai até o Windows7.

Para saber quais modos o seu sistema faça o seguinte caminho (se você usa Windows):

- Clique com o direito do Mouse/Rato na Área de Trabalho
- Selecione Resolução de tela
- Clique em Configurações Avançadas
- Na janela que abriu procure o botão <kbd>Lista modos</kbd>

Vai aparecer isto:

[image: resoluções]

Observe que todos "modos" só tem suporte para `32 bits`, penso eu que usar 16bits hoje em dia é desnecessário

> Pelo que li, sistemas modernos não precisam mais de 16bits, ou qualquer coisa inferior ao 32bits, existem técnicas (que provavelmente só programas com acessos de administrador podem usar), uma delas é colocar o programa para iniciar com modo de compatibilidade, no entanto o processo é todo manual e não tem como fazer **isto por Java** (a não ser se for uma gambiarra usando as APIs do Windows), exemplo:
>
> [image: 8bits e 16bits no Windows8 e 10]

---

### Como detectar suporte para mudança do Display com Java

Para ter certeza se suporta você pode testar a função:

```
 GraphicsDevice.isDisplayChangeSupported
```

E no `setDisplayMode` use *try/catch*:

```
try {
    device.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    //Pega o erro e.getMessage
}
```

### Como colocar o JFrame em fullescreen

Agora para deixar o `JFrame` em fullscreen, independente do suporte da sua placa de video e/ou driver você pode usar assim:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //Maxmiza
frame.setUndecorated(true); //Remove a decoração da janela
```

Isso vai deixar o seu `JFrame` em *fullscreen*, mas não significa que vai mudar a resolução da tela.

---

Deve ficar tudo assim (aperte <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> para fechar):

> **Nota:** adicionei o `javax.swing.JOptionPane` somente para exibir mensagens para saber o que ocorreu

```
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
    {
        final GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        final GraphicsDevice device = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

        final int width = 640;
        final int height = 480;

        if (device.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
            final DisplayMode displayMode = new DisplayMode(width, height, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);

            try {
                device.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mudou a resolução");
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                device.setFullScreenWindow(null);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sem suporte para mudar a resolução");
        }

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Minha primeira janela");
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //Maxmiza
        frame.setUndecorated(true); //Remove a decoração da janela
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```